# what is the use of running shell script like "$ ls -la | script.sh"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

To get total number of lines read, why we are using `ls -la | script.sh` ? 
Why we cant execute normal way like `script.sh` ? 
Note that script.sh is the shell script program.

Comment: Well, what is `script.sh` doing?

Comment: Do you understand what `ls -la` does and what `|` does?

Comment: Presumably to get the lines from `ls -la`.... you'd have to post `script.sh` for us to tell you for sure.

Comment: @h.j.k. Actually script.sh is doing is to read the total number of lines as well as find the largest file size. But the major problem is I do not know the use of `| script.sh` here.

Comment: @Blorgbeard that's what I really need to know?

Comment: This same question was put on hold 18 hours ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341422/shell-scripting-that-gives-the-summary-of-ls-la-command-in-linux I'm glad it's been answered now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking it down bit by bit:

```
ls -la
```

List **a**ll files (including dotfiles) in **l**ong format.

```
|
```

Sends the output of the command on the left to the command on the right

```
script.sh
```

Executes the script.

So the output of `ls -la` will be sent via stdin to `script.sh`.

Comment: It means all the output of ls -la is goes to the script.sh right ?

Answer (score 0):

To get total  number of lines, that is files in your case, simply

```
ls | wc -l
```